# Is it possible to invoke the no modifier class or default class via reflection

Tags: java, reflection

i want to invoke main method of default access class Demo:

```
class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

and i call it from another class like :

```
    String[] str = {};
    Class cls = Class.forName(packClassName);        
    Method thisMethod = cls.getMethod("main", String[].class);        
    thisMethod.setAccessible(true);        
    thisMethod.invoke(cls.newInstance(), (Object) str);
```

But i get exception i.e.

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class javaedit.Editor can not access a member of class Demo with modifiers ""
        at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:95)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:366)
```

Comment: Could you show us how you try to invoke it?

Comment: Please don't post relevant code as commend. Instead include it to question via [[edit]] option.

Comment: Do you really need to use reflection, or are you asking about reflection only because you see 'Reflection' in the stack trace?  I would write a public class in the same package which calls the Demo.main method directly, without using reflection at all.

Comment: @VGR No, that i know, actually i hv to use reflection becouse i am calling it from outside of the package...

Comment: ok @Pshemo But I have still having same problem, when i make class as public class Demo it work well but it is not working when i put class a default type.

Comment: Are you using full class name like "package1.package2.Demo" as `packClassName`? My code works for me even when I have Demo class in separate packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main problem of your code is that you are trying to invoke static method on instance of class. Static methods don't belong to objects but to entire class, so instead instance use `null` as first argument of `invoke` method

```
String[] str = {};
Class cls = Class.forName(packClassName);        
Method thisMethod = cls.getMethod("main", String[].class);        
thisMethod.setAccessible(true);        

thisMethod.invoke(null, new Object[]{str});//ver 1
thisMethod.invoke(null, (Object)str);//ver 2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the full name of the class this can be done with reflection, for example given a package private class:

```
class AcessCheck {

    public static final void printStuff() {
        System.out.println("Stuff");
    }
}
```

You can invoke the `printStuff` method with reflection using the following:

```
    final Class<?> c = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass("com.mypackage.AcessCheck");
    final Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("printStuff", (Class[]) null);
    m.setAccessible(true);
    m.invoke(null, (Object[]) null);
```